# REST - Rails API Frontend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, api, rest

I want to create a **Rails + React.JS application** and I've seen that most of the tutorials on the web mention about REST API. The data I want to be served through JSON

I understand what's a REST API but what I do not understand is how does the frontend gets served to the user?

Do I need to have **2 Rails projects**, one for the **API**, from which we get JSON data (like users etc) and one for the **View Layer** which will return an HTML with plenty of javascript ?

And what if I create *only a simple rails app* (**not** API), which has controllers for the view-layer (to render *html/javascript*) and controllers for json data (which would be "**API**") ? Would that be a **good practice** or not?

All I want to create is an app that: you visit a page, say **/users/1**, get the HTML content (which would be mostly referencing scripts and that's it) and another route responsible for json data from which we pull data, let's say /api/users/1.json (which would be a **namespace route** to match the api folder in controllers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do here is to use react-rails. It also allows server side rendering (no REST API).

https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails

Just run `gem 'react-rails'` , `bundle install`, and `rails g react:install`

Then you just list components to your application.js file like below and can start using react components from automatically created folder at `app/assets/javascripts/components/`

```
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
```